# How to loop an animation and also incrementing one transform to make it look continues

Tags: animation, bones, pose-mode, timeline

Assume i have a walk cycle , and i have someone walking in it , wont it be too strange that the person goes back to where he started 1 sec ago every time , so how can i make this animation loop and make him go forward at the same time?

Comment: you need to make a "still" walk cycle so that it looks like the character doesn't move forward, then use the Follow Path constraint so that he follows a curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer moonboots provided was good  , to make a "still" walk cycle so that it looks like the character doesn't move forward, then use the Follow Path constraint so that he follows a curve